# woocommerce menu Cart , how to hide the cart tab when the cart is empty

Tags: wordpress

Please, I need your help.
I installed the plugin: 
woo commerce for WordPress.
And the cart icon now on my Menu Bar.
When i clicked on it , i will redirect to the shop page,
I don't want to do that.
I want  hide the cart tab icon  when the cart is empty : http://grab.by/AykC

If that is impossible,  How can i redirect my tab button when it is empty to a custom page ? Thanks
Regards
A.J.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

can you check this

Go to WooCommerce-->Settings-->Products.
The Cart settings are near the bottom i think

Comment: I installed the following plugin:https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-menu-cart/    -  I can't hide the button: http://grab.by/Ayou  - on my Menu bar,I want to hide the button when i don't have any item on it.

Comment: I don't find any option for Cart setting, Can do please, Take a screenshot of the Cart setting that you have.

Answer (score -1):

From your dashboard:

- Go to Settings and then Menu Cart Search
- On that page there is an option called "Always display cart, even if it's empty"
- Untick the checkbox beside that
- Save the changes and the cart should only appear when there are items in the cart.

Comment: Thanks sir for your feedback. I did it that, but it is not working. It is still my Menu tab appear on the Menu bar, and when i click on it , then it will redirect the the Shop.

Comment: Try ticking that and saving it, then untick it and save it.

Comment: If that is impossible,  How can i redirect my tab button when it is empty to a custom page ? Thanks